# Determinants Quadratic polynomials and iota in characteristic equation .

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, determinant

**question:**

Given $A,B$ be two  square matrices (**with real entries** )of order $2$  where

$AB=BA$ $, \det(A)=\alpha>0$  , $\det(A+i\alpha B)=0$

then find value of L where ,

$L=\det(A^2-\alpha A B+\alpha^2B^2)$

**my attempt:**

we know for $\det(A+xB)=x^2\det B+mx+\det A$ where $m= \ tr((adj A) B)$

put $x=i\alpha$ we get,

$\det(A+i\alpha B)=-\alpha^2\det B+mi\alpha+\det A=0\implies m=0\\$ &$\ \ \ \alpha \det B=1$

i don't know how to proceed further .please help in solving to get final answer . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are supposed to assume $A$ and $B$ are real matrices (as the answer is not determined if $A$ and $B$ can have complex entries).  Note that for real matrices, 
$\det(A+i\alpha B) = 0$ implies $\det(A-i\alpha B) = 0$, and thus $B^{-1} A$ has eigenvalues $\pm i \alpha$.

Comment: yes entries are real ... but i still don't get you ....How eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A$ help me in finding value of L ..please elaborate some more

Comment: If $C = A^{-1} B$, $\det(L) = \det(A^2) \det(I - \alpha C + \alpha^2 C^2)$.
$\det(I - \alpha C + \alpha^2 C^2) = \prod_r (1 - \alpha r + \alpha^2 r^2)$ where the product is over the eigenvalues of $C$.